# Download a notebook (or any type of file) from the cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Let us say that I have a Notebook in the Wolfram Programming Cloud called `foo.nb`.

If I try `CloudGet["foo.nb"]`, what I get back is a CloudObject (or the link to it), which in any case does not allow me to download the notebook itself.

Is there a way/function/trick to obtain a link to download `foo.nb` to the Desktop?

Comment: You should not be experiencing this behavior. If you save a notebook to the cloud, `CloudGet` / `CloudImport` should return the `Notebook` expression, which you can then open with `CreateDocument`, or save locally. I just tested this and had no problem. How did you save the notebook?

Comment: @mfvonh That solves partially what I want do. I explain briefly: after someone fills a FormFunction deployed on the cloud, I want their browser to automatically start the download of the notebook, just as when one clicks on a demonstration like the one in the link. [link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/downloadauthornb.cgi?name=Tries)

Or at least give them the link to copy and paste it on their web address bar.

Comment: Is the notebook generated based on data submitted in the form?

Comment: I want to generate random notebook assignments for my students. The information they will provide in the form is their login data (Student-ID number and a PIN). When they submit, the FormFunction checks if such file was already generated by a previous execution and should deliver the link to download the notebook previously generated, if such file doesn't exists yet, it is generated via a function `GenerateAssignment[]` and at the end, the student should get a link to their new generated assignment.

Comment: You could create an API that sends the requested files to a 3rd party server (for example by emailing them or sharing them to dropbox). It may be possible to do this directly with HTTPRequest & MultipartElement.